# Is it possible to publish a ArcGIS .mxd file in OpenLayers?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, openlayers-2, arcgis-desktop, mxd

It is possible to publish a .mxd in OpenLayers? I am using ArcGIS 10.0.

Answer (score 8):

***Short Answer:*** No, not directly

---

***Long Answer***
You need to understand that these are two different technologies.

a ArcMap Document (.mxd) is a file which tells ArcMap which layers to use and how to render them etc.

OpenLayers is a JavaScript Library that is used for creating application which consume Web Services.

A .mxd file can only be opened in ArcMap, but if you have ArcGIS server, you could then publish that map as a MapService, which could then be consumed in a custom OpenLayers based Application.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible, if you use ArcGis Server. There are 2 steps:

1) publish your ".mxd" (really, there are data [stored in gdb, or enterprise geodatabase, or another source] and .mxd)

2) then you can diplay this map in browser. You can use OpenLayers (in this situation you must use WMS) or ArcGis API for JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You could create tiles of your .mxd and then publish those to an open service such as OpenLayers.

Comment: Are you able to provide more detail about how you would tile an MXD file?

Comment: @PolyGeo: I belive this can be done with third party Extensions like Arc2Earth

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe [**Connecting ArcGIS to TileMill with Arc2Earth Sync**](https://www.mapbox.com/blog/connecting-arcgis-tilemill/) does look like it would go most of the way from an **MXD** to **OpenLayers** - thanks for pointing it out